# How to start / stop Java process in the Command Prompt?

Tags: java, command-line, windows-process

I have Java 1.8.0 running in Windows. How can i start/stop this process in the Command Prompt?

Comment: It's very difficult to tell you how to start the program with the information you've given.  The may be many command line arguments and it's impossible to guess what they are.  See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html) for information on getting your Java command line setup.  That will at least get you started.

Answer (score 1):

not mine, check if it helps

```
taskkill /f /im jqs.exe
taskkill /f /im javaw.exe
taskkill /f /im java.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + C in the command.

If you need exit elegantly, you need program for it. You can refer to apache's [library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) for more.